# Deploy Azure function to app service in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-eventhub

I created Azure function with Event-Hub trigger to insert data to SQL database in Microsoft visual studio 2019.
Normally, It can work with local system. But when I deploy to Microsoft Azure the Azure function will not working.

**In chart**

- Memory working set has event.
- Function Exception Count doesn't have any event.

[image]

Comment: Do you have "always on" enabled on the App Service? This looks like your Function App is being shut down due to no requests coming in. An Event Hub trigger will *not* wake up your Function App.

Comment: Glad it helped ! If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: the title of the question doesn't reflect the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

To view function execution count we need to configure as below:

- When we have published our ***Event hub function to Azure make sure that the below configuration is there in our function:***

[image]

- Also make sure that we have enable Application insight enabled for monitoring as below:

[image]

***OUTPUT:-***
[image]

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140164/azure-function-shows-0-executions-on-azure-portal) as suggested @[***IVAN YANG***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10185816/ivan-yang) and this [***BLOG***](https://www.codewithadam.com/trigger-azure-functions-on-event-hub/) .

***UPDATE:-1***

It may be you have not tested your function in Code+test .
***To view the function execution count make sure that we have Test our function from portal> Functions> Your Function> COde+Test>Run*** as below :
[image]

Then make a refresh or reload the page and you will be able to see the Count as well.
[image]

Comment: I did it as your suggestion. But it can't not working. I'm not sure about this problem because this is free app service.

Comment: Could you please let us know are you able to access your function app in Azure.

Comment: Yes, I can access to my function app. I would like to fix this problem. Please let me know

Comment: Do you have the same in configuration  as on suggested in answer

Comment: Could you please refer to this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140164/azure-function-shows-0-executions-on-azure-portal)if not.

Comment: Yes, the same configuration. I try to create a new project then deploy to app service but it the same response. it not working.

Comment: Hello@Akarapol P ,Please check my updated answer, May be you need to test it in portal as shown in `UPDATE-1`Answer. Could you please try & let me know .Thank you

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. It already worked.